# The connection to the website was reset. Error Code: INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE

Tags: internet-explorer, iis, microsoft-edge

I am getting the following error from my website:

> The connection to the website was reset.
>   Error Code: INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE

The website is available on Firefox and Chrome, but will not display on IE/Edge.
We host this site on our webserver. All other websites are ok.
This is an older Aspx Web application using CLR v2.

I have tried a couple of fixes suggested by Microsoft:

> The Error Code: INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE means that the connection was interrupted or it failed to download the content. Let's start by restoring the advanced settings in the Internet Options.
>
> Go to Internet Options (type it in the Cortana search box) > Advanced tab > click Restore advanced settings > uncheck "Do not save encrypted pages to disk." After that, click Apply and OK. Let us know how it went by posting back.

Which had no effect also I cleared the browser cache, flushed the DNS via IpConfig and even set up a new website in IIS with a new App Pool, all to no effect.

The error message is very generic so I am a bit lost, especially as the site is visible to FF and Chrome.

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi Mike, what is the address of 'your website' or are you developing/testing an intranet site on your company's network? (intranet)

Comment: To debug websites with IE first go Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages". Save changes. Open your website (test/dev/production) in IE... then select the File>Properties menu. Note which IE security zone 'your website' maps to (expected Intranet). Then open the Dev tool (f12). On the Console tab you will now find blocked content errors (ActiveX filtering, tracking protection), markup errors, and security errors listed. On the Emulation tab of the f12 dev tool you will find out which IE emulation mode is used and how its established. Post details.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for your input, I will give it a go and report back. The website address is: http://www.lenovovseriestradein.com/

Comment: HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
about:blank

HTML1527: DOCTYPE expected. Consider adding a valid HTML5 doctype: "<!DOCTYPE html>".
about:blank (1,1)

HTML1405: Invalid character: U+0000 NULL. Null characters should not be used.
about:blank (1,14)

HTML1507: Unexpected character: U+0000 NULL. Null characters should not be used.
about:blank (1,14)

HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
www.lenovovseriestradein.com

HTML1527: DOCTYPE expected. Consider adding a valid HTML5 doctype: "<!DOCTYPE html>".
www.lenovovseriestradein.com (1,1)

HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
dnserror.htm

Comment: And the Emulation Document Mode = 11, BrowserProfile = Desktop, User Agent  = IE 11

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for your input. The site is one that we host and IS available on Chrome Firefox etc. There has been an IE update which seems to have broken this old site. I was looking for a fix (probably to the HTML Header) as I have tried the above solutions with no luck.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?  I'm having the same problem.  Thanks.

Comment: If I put the site into security - Trusted Sites and set the custom level - User Authentication - Automatic logon only in Intranet Zone, I don't get the error.  But, I'm on a laptop and when I go into the office, I am now asked to enter the login and password.

Answer (score 3):

I had the similar problem and in my case it seems to be caused by cached credentials.
To ensure that you have the same root cause do the following:

1. Enable Developer Tool in IE (F12)
2. Open Network tab
3. Try to open your web site URL
4. If you get 401 Unauthorized error then the problem most likely is there

To fix that:

1. Open IE "Internet options"
2. Open Advanced tab
3. Uncheck "Enable Integrated Windows Authentication" checkbox

After that you will be always prompted to enter credentials when you open your web site in new instance of IE, but at least this will solve the problem.

Another option is probably to clean Credentials Manager, but i didn't manage to find exactly this record.

Answer (score 0):

Try this option...It works for me...
Windows-->Start--> internet options-->Security-->Trusted sites-->Sites-->Add url (uncheck https)....

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The website may require a certificate for authentication. If this is missing the browser may just display `INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE`. Contact the server administrator to see if a certificate is required.

After the installation you need to restart your browser before trying to access the website again.

Source: Own experience.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation. Our junior sysadmin added to URL rewrite module string with

```
{HTTP_USER_AGENT}
Matches the Pattern
*Trident*
```

And all IE browser has stopped working, removing this string helped.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, in my case it turned out the problem went away after removing Kaspersky Internet Security software. There was no explicit blocking, just KIS v21 software was no longer compatible after Windows 10 updates. It stopped Microsoft updates & help & many other functions but Chrome continued working. Microsoft automated troubleshooter is useless in most cases, it needs a lot more work, logging debug & informing the user. Manual steps to troubleshoot were about >6 pages long (snippets from multiple sources) with many, many time consuming steps. Kaspersky stopped updating the software even after normal renewing subscription, a new product with new subscription was required. I eventually replaced it with another product from another company. Now everything is working again.